# Wipe tablet and install new ROM

Tags: rom-flashing, rom, samsung-galaxy-player

I have the Galaxy S Wifi 5 Player, I have a rooted ROM I installed more than a year ago.

I completely forgot the process of ROM installation and I hope someone can sum up a checklist so I don't find myself with a bricked device.

Note: I've backed up all the data on my device, so I don't care about the current data.

The deal is I want to install [this ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2235446).

Here are the installation instructions:

Installation on the Galaxy Player 5.0/ Galaxy S 5.0

> 1. Installing from cm10.1/ Updating PAC
> 2. Download rom and latest gapps
> 3. Download the appropriate [Sultan kernel](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2252851) or [KKernel](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2286381) if you want
> 4. Put the files on your device
> 5. Reboot into recovery
> 6. Wipe dalvik cache
> 7. At what order should I install the zips? "or do adb sideload if you want" - what's that?
> 8. Reboot
> 9. Profit!
> 10. From any other rom do same as above, but in addition, wipe data, dalvik, system, and dbdata (look under mounts and storage)

I don't understand these (of the above list):

1) don't know what's cm10.1/Updating PAC (how do I?)
2) what's gapps
3) what are they and how to install them? are they mandatory?
4) at what location?
7) how do I install the zips? what's adb sideload?

Comment: If you are going to repost this, delete your other question.

Comment: @VarnerBeast14, sure I did. I just thought the other one was badly formatted in first place and already received bad attitude. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if you are already rooted and running a custom ROM, you will want to follow these steps, and I hope you know what they mean, because I am going to try and keep them as simple as possible:

1. backup any of your data you want. Google does this automatically with some stuff, but the other stuff you can use [Nandroid Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.h3r3t1c.onnandbup&hl=en).
2. Reboot into recovery.
3. Wipe all data/factory reset.
4. Flash the ROM in the recovery tool. I use TWRP so I just click install and then navigate to where I have downloaded and saved the .zip file that I want, but yours should be similar no matter what recovery you are using.
5. Flash the most recent gapps package in the same way as the ROM's zip. These are the Google Apps that you will need.

That should be it. I simplified it so that you can understand, but if you have questions, leave them below. If this stills seems foreign to you, you might want to look for a video guide on YouTube or something. The process is very similar for almost all phones. Just different files and slightly different methods depending on which recovery and such you use.

Comment: I have CWM-based recovery. I wiped data, but it said 'skipping format'. Also it says 'wipe dalvik cache', what does it refer to? My goal is to WIPE the device without leaving any remains, just install the new ROM wiping all prior evidence.

Comment: then just wipe everything. That's easy. Wipe Dalvik Cache just wipes some extra data. To be honest, I don't know exactly what it is, but I wipe that every time I update my ROM. But if you want a full wipe, just wipe everything.

Comment: OK. Now, I'm at the installation phase, what from the 3 zips should I install first (Kernel, PacRom, Gapps) I believe Gapps should be the last right?

Comment: From the [Kernel's page](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2252851) I chose "Sultan-kernel-Venturi-r5b2-USB-OTG-USA.zip" Is this the right download (I have the USA version of the device, but I didn't understand what's all the bunch of files in that collection.

Comment: Usually I just flash my ROM and then the Gapps, but if this says to flash the Kernel, then do that first as well.

Comment: What Kernel should I install (see prev. comment)?

Comment: I really don't know. That guide is about as clear as it needs to be. If you can't handle that, I'm not sure you need to be flashing custom ROMs.

Comment: What will happen if I connect my device to PC as mass storage and format the connected disks via PC, will it brick my device? Will I be able to enter recovery mode? Will I be able to use Odin to re-install the system?